# c++ implement of array broadcast

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

In python language, we can use `A[A!=0]=-10` to trans all the non-zero value in A to -10. How can I implement this function in C++ language or is here any similar function in 3rd party?

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat A(3, 3, CV_16SC1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            A.at<short>(i, j) = i + j;
        }
    }
    for (auto& value : A) if (value != 2) value = -10;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using 'cv::mat' to process CT data. I want to realize contraststreching func. But the 'cv::contraststreching' requires the input to be uint8 type. But the CT data have -2000 pixel value. So it can't be used.

Comment: Keep it simple: `for (auto &value : A) if (value != 0) value = -10;`.

Comment: Quite useful! Furthermore, may I ask how to process `cv::mat` class? Because there is no `cv::mat::begin`.

Comment: If I can see `cv::mat` definition, then I may be able to answer..

Comment: Sry. I mistook something.  The error info is `in this range-based 'for' statement, no instance of "cv::Mat::begin" matches the argument list. object type is: cv::Mat`.

Comment: @JiangHan *or is here any similar function in 3rd party?* -- [std::replace_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range-based `for` loops will not work since the `cv::Mat::begin()` is a member function template. You'll have to use `begin<mat_type>()` and `end<mat_type>()`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    cv::Mat A(3, 3, CV_16SC1);

    using mtype = short;                              // convenience typedef

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            A.at<mtype>(i, j) = i + j;                // using mtype
        }
    }

    // using mtype:
    for(auto it = A.begin<mtype>(); it != A.end<mtype>(); ++it) {
        if(*it != 2) *it = -10;
    }

    // print result:
    std::copy(A.begin<mtype>(), A.end<mtype>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<mtype>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Or using the [`std::replace_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) algorithm to replace all non `2`'s with `-10`:

```cpp
    std::replace_if(A.begin<mtype>(), A.end<mtype>(),  // using mtype
        [](auto& value) { return value != 2; }, -10);
```

Output:

```
-10
-10
2
-10
2
-10
2
-10
-10
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `std::ranges::replace` in C++20:

```
std::vector<int> values = {1,2,3,1,2,5,3,165};
std::ranges::replace(values, 3, 999);
```

And, similarly, `std::ranges::replace_if` in C++20:

```
std::vector<int> values = {1,2,0,1,0,5,3,165};
std::ranges::replace_if(values, [](int a) { return a != 0;}, -10);
```

You can see it in
[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:71,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:71,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:71,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:71,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+values+%3D+%7B1,2,0,1,0,5,3,165%7D%3B%0A++++std::ranges::replace_if(values,+%5B%5D(int+a)+%7B+return+a+!!%3D+0%3B+%7D,++-10)%3B%0A++++std::ranges::copy(values,+std::ostream_iterator%3Cint%3E%7Bstd::cout,+%22,+%22%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.1191222570533,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:25,l:%274%27,m:43.87755102040816,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.122448979591844,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.880877742946716,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

It is also possible to use `std::not_equal_to` with `std::bind_front` instead of the lambda, if you prefer it that way, [like this](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:25,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:25,selectionStartColumn:21,selectionStartLineNumber:25,startColumn:21,startLineNumber:25),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Range%3E%0Avoid+print(std::string_view+msg,+const+Range+%26+elements)%0A%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+msg%3B%0A++++std::ranges::copy(elements,+std::ostream_iterator%3Cint%3E%7Bstd::cout,+%22,+%22%7D)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+values+%3D+%7B1,2,0,1,0,5,3,165%7D%3B%0A++++print(%22Before:+%22,+values)%3B%0A++++std::ranges::replace_if(values,+%5B%5D(int+a)+%7B+return+a+!!%3D+0%3B+%7D,++-10)%3B%0A++++print(%22replaced+with+lambda:+%22,+values)%3B%0A%0A++++values+%3D+%7B1,2,0,1,0,5,3,165%7D%3B%0A++++%0A++++print(%22Before:+%22,+values)%3B%0A++++std::ranges::replace_if(values,+std::bind_front(std::not_equal_to%7B%7D,+0),++-20)%3B%0A++++print(%22replaced+with+std::bind_front:+%22,+values)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.1191222570533,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:25,l:%274%27,m:43.87755102040816,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.122448979591844,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.880877742946716,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Edit: here is the `bind_front` code (from the above link):

```
std::ranges::replace_if(values, std::bind_front(std::not_equal_to{}, 0),  -20);
```

Answer (score 0):

In STL container there is a function that has similar behavior. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> example_vector{0,1,4,1,5};
    for_each(example_vector.begin(), example_vector.end(), [](auto& a) {  if (a != 0)a = -10; });
}
```

Although the syntax seems not simple like python, it is optimized, and may be parallelized by execution policy.

Comment: May I ask how to process `cv::mat` class as this class doesn't support `begin()` func. My mat size is 512*512*200, short type. So I wish there is no need to trans mat to vector concerning to the efficiency

Comment: @JiangHan Then I do not have answer.. Maybe you have to write your own iteration function.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Python’s built-in lists also don’t have array broadcast syntax. OP is presumably using a numpy array. I think there are numerical linear algebra libraries for C++ which provide a similar syntax (e.g. Armadillo, IIRC?).